# Deleting multiple selected rows in GridControl and in Database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

This is my GridControl
[image]

And these are the selected rows
[image]
I am using these lines of code to delete them from grid control

```
IEnumerable<int> selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows().Where(rowHandle => gridView1.IsDataRow(rowHandle)).OrderBy(rowHandle => rowHandle);
        for (int i = selectedRows.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
        
            gridView1.DeleteRow(selectedRows.ElementAt(i));


        }
```

Now, How can I delete these rows also from my table in the database.
I have also tried this and it doesn't work either

```
 foreach (var rowHandle in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
        {
            var itemsNames1 = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["SaleId"].ToString().ToList());
            foreach (var row in itemsNames1)
            {

                var ctx = new BizPlusEntities();
                var get = ctx.Sales.SingleOrDefault(a => a.SaleId.Equals(row));
                ctx.Sales.Remove(get);
                ctx.SaveChanges();

             
            }
        }
```

Comment: How did you loaded from database in the first place?

Comment: i am using a binding source

Answer (score 0):

This Works Perfectly Fine

```
 private void simpleButton2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btx = new BizPlusEntities();

        foreach (int i in gridView1.GetSelectedRows())
        {
            DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
            int id = (int)row[0];
            var get = btx.Sales.SingleOrDefault(a => a.SaleId == id);
            var getiingUniqueNum = btx.Sales.SingleOrDefault(x => x.SaleId == id)?.UniqueSaleNumber ?? "No Number";
            var list = btx.ItemSaleDatas.Where(x => x.UniqueSaleNumber == getiingUniqueNum).ToList();
            btx.ItemSaleDatas.RemoveRange(list);
           btx.SaveChanges();
            btx.Sales.Remove(get);
            btx.SaveChanges();

        }
        IEnumerable<int> selectedRows = gridView1.GetSelectedRows().Where(rowHandle => gridView1.IsDataRow(rowHandle)).OrderBy(rowHandle => rowHandle);
        for (int i = selectedRows.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
        
            gridView1.DeleteRow(selectedRows.ElementAt(i));
          

        }


    }
```